# Display value from dynamic buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate a series of buttons from a loop. On each button click, it should display the file.path of each button. The id is assigned dynamically from the loop itself. It is only displaying for the first one. here is the code:

*Onclickling the button, it display the path for doc 1. But when clicking the second button, it display the path for doc1 too. It should display the path of doc 2*

```
var result = {"data":"{\"files\":[{\"name\":\"doc1.pdf\",\"title\":\"networking\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc1.pdf\"},{\"name\":\"doc2.pdf\",\"title\":\"Armoogum\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc2.pdf\"}]}","isSuccessful":true};
 var str= '';
 var files = JSON.parse(result.data).files;

                    for(var file, i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                      file = files[i];

                      str += file.name + '<br />' + file.title + '<br/>' + '<input type="hidden" id="b" value="'+ file.path +'" />' + '<button onclick="add()">Add</button> '+  '<br/>' ;
                    }

                    alert(str);                                  
                    $("#viewlist").html(str);  
       function add() {

        var b = document.getElementById('b').value;

        alert(b);
      }
```

I will really appreciate it if i can get some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your buttons have the same id, that is not going to work.  There are a couple of ways of doing this.  I modified your HTML slightly to group each section so you can easily find the associated hidden field for the button.  I also passed in a reference to the button being clicked to the add function:

```
var result = {"data":"{\"files\":[{\"name\":\"doc1.pdf\",\"title\":\"networking\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc1.pdf\"},{\"name\":\"doc2.pdf\",\"title\":\"Armoogum\",\"path\":\"mfpreader.comze.com\\\/files\\\/doc2.pdf\"}]}","isSuccessful":true};
var str= '';
var files = JSON.parse(result.data).files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  str += file.name + '<br /><div class="fileSection">' + file.title + '<br/>' + '<input class="fileName" type="hidden" id="b" value="'+ file.path +'" />' + '<button onclick="add(this)">Add</button> '+  '</div><br/>' ;

  $("#viewlist").html(str);  

function add(btn) { 
  var b = $(btn).closest('.fileSection').find('.fileName').val();
  alert(b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `str` defined? I suspect it might be inside the `for` loop, but you want to make sure that you define it before the loop:

```
var str = '';
for(var file, i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    file = files[i];
    str += file.name + '<br />' + file.title + '<br/>' + '<input type="hidden" id="b" value="'+ file.path +'" />' + '<button onclick="add()">Add</button> '+  '<br/>' ;
}
```

I think the output is then what you are looking for.

Comment: I am sorry, i missed it while copying. Onclickling the button, it display the path for doc 1. But when clicking the second button, it display the path for doc1 too. It should display the path of doc 2.